# SqlAlchemy : how to use relationship() together with Array of ForeignKey Column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am wondering if I could use sqlalchemy relationship() with Array of ForeignKey,
like the below examples :

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.types import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database import Base


class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    topic_name = Column(String)


class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rooms'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    room_name = Column(String)
    body = Column(String)

    topics_id = Column(ARRAY(Integer, ForeignKey("topics.id")))

    topics = relationship("Topic", foreign_keys='topics_id', uselist=True) #Single-direction
```

The relationship is that a Room has many of topics in it, but a Topic does not need to belong to any room.

Since the Room model already has a topics_id field that store array of foreign_keys of Topics model,
so I tried use this topics_id, passing into relationship()

Plus I do not want the Topic to has a link to Room model

but it give me this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Room->rooms, expression 'topics_id' failed to locate a name ("name 'topics_id' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'models.Room'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a many-to-many relation for a schema like this. In the many-to-many relation, your topics can be a part of many rooms and every room can have multiple topics.

You can read about it here on the sqlalchemy official documentation

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I looked at the given url, it seemed to fit what I want. 
However, I am just wondering that in this case, does a Room model still needs to have a field (topics_id) to store Foreign_key of Topics ? if I am going to have association_table implementing.
Like, can I access Foreign_key of Topics from a association_table instead ?

Comment: You can surely do that, although adding the field makes the data more accessible.